# Iterate through Quadrilateral pixels

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a quadrilateral on my picture box. I know the pixel coordinates of vertexes: A(x1,y1), B(x2,y2), C(x3,y3), D(x4,y4).[quadrilateral example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EuRS.jpg) 
Is there a simple way to iterate through all pixels inside the quadrilateral?

Comment: You're looking for a triangle/quadrilateral rasterization algorithm.

Comment: what do you mean by iterating through quadrilateral pixels

Comment: It would make more sense if you asked "*i would like to iterate through all the x y points inside a quadrilateral*" However this is a maths problem, and you have attempted nothing and just want the answer. so this a low quality question

Comment: [The Point in Polygon Problem for Arbitrary Polygons](http://www.inf.usi.ch/hormann/papers/Hormann.2001.TPI.pdf)